# Avt Manta GigE camera with prosilica_driver

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm using the **prosilica_driver node** to access images from my camera (AVT Manta G235B) in **ROS indigo** running under **Ubuntu 14.04**.
The problem I'm experiencing is twofold

- First, a **lower framerate** (about **10 Hz**
  according to rostopic hz) than the
  expected one (**50 Hz** from datasheet
  and about 50 Hz tested on Windows
  with the camera provider software).
- Second, **Rosbag** (via rqt_bag) is
  complaining like that when I try to **log the camera frame**

  [INFO] [WallTime: 1411548138.205121] Recording to /home/ragingbit/test_2014-09-24-10-42-18.bag.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_bag/bag_widget.py", line 235, in _handle_record_clicked
  self._timeline.record_bag(record_filename)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_bag/bag_timeline.py", line 643, in record_bag
  self.add_bag(self._recorder.bag)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_bag/bag_timeline.py", line 167, in add_bag
  self._timeline_frame.reset_timeline()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_bag/timeline_frame.py", line 916, in reset_timeline
  self.emit_play_region()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_bag/timeline_frame.py", line 256, in emit_play_region
  self.scene().selected_region_changed.emit(*self.play_region)
  TypeError: BagTimeline.selected_region_changed[Time, Time].emit(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

Any help is really appreciated! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193377/avt-manta-gige--camera-with-prosilica_driver/) by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 706 on 2014-09-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) on 2014-09-24**:
Thank you very much for the suggestions. Is there any documentation/user guide for that?

**Comment by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) on 2014-09-24**:
Do I have to download the Vimba SDK form the official website?
I tried to launch the avt_vimba_node but I get the following error:
[ERROR] [1411557229.963177527]: [AVT_Vimba_ROS]: Could not start Vimba system: TL not loaded.
Error: API not started.

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2014-09-25**:
Unfortunately yes, you'll have to install manually the SDK in your system. Just follow the instructions from the VIMBA SDK website.

**Comment by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) on 2014-09-25**:
Hi Miquel,
thank you for your assistance! the node is kind of working also for my Manta G-235B. I'm only experiencing issues with the framerate (10 Hz instead of 50 Hz!). As on the VimbaViewer it is working, can you suggest me some settings I could try to modify for the avt_vimba_node?

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2014-09-25**:
Check if the exposure is in automatic or in manual. Also check if the exposure time allows for 50 Hz, which has to be quite fast. Experience with extremely low exposure times and check "rostopic hz" even though the image will be dark.

**Comment by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) on 2014-09-26**:
Exactly, that was the issue, thanks! The node is mostly working with my camera too, even though I guess some of the options available in VimbaViewer are still missing in the ROS counterpart. Anyway, great job!

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2014-09-26**:
Thanks for the compliment. If you'd like to help please do so. Fork the repo and perform "pull requests" with any improvements you believe are worth.

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2015-03-23**:
Did you ever solve your `rqt_bag` error? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd recommend you [avt_vimba_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/avt_vimba_camera) which is developed with the new API and I'm currently maintaining.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2014-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0